# PHP GD cropping PNG doesn't work

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg, crop

I'm creating a function to crop images using PHP GD.
The function works perfectly for JPEG images but when I try to use the same function for PNG I just get a blank page and the following errors when I inspect the page in chrome:

I realize this is a javascript error, but this is probably something chrome does? This is what happens when i visit the IMAGE URL.  If i replicate this with the JPEG code it works perfectly.

Edit: in Firefox it says "The image [URL] cannot be displayed because it contains errors.  The below js error is just a chrome error and isn't very relevant.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
>   data_loader.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'hasAttribute' of null global-shortcut.js:9

The working JPEG code is as follows:

```
$fileName = $_POST['file'];
$jpeg_quality = 100;
$ratio = $_POST['r'];

$src = '/var/www/admin/public_html/images/'.$fileName;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$target = '/var/www/admin/public_html/images/crop/'.$fileName;

$thumb_width = $_POST['w'] / $ratio;
$thumb_height = $_POST['h'] / $ratio;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0,
                   0, 
                   $_POST['x'] / $ratio, $_POST['y'] / $ratio,
                   $width, $height,
                   $width, $height);

imagejpeg($thumb, $target, $jpeg_quality);
```

The Broken PNG code is as follows:

```
$fileName = $_POST['file'];
$jpeg_quality = 100;
$ratio = $_POST['r'];

$src = '/var/www/admin/public_html/images/'.$fileName;
$image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
$target = '/var/www/admin/public_html/images/crop/'.$fileName;

$thumb_width = $_POST['w'] / $ratio;
$thumb_height = $_POST['h'] / $ratio;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0,
                   0, 
                   $_POST['x'] / $ratio, $_POST['y'] / $ratio,
                   $width, $height,
                   $width, $height);

imagepng($thumb, $target, $jpeg_quality);
```

Comment: That's a JS error... you need to show that code.

Comment: I realize it's a JS error but there is no code, that's what happens when i visit the image URL. @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.
imagepng() function takes quality argument from 0 to 9 
imagejpeg() function takes quality argument from 0 to 100